# Word for one's pursuit of deadly obligation?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Maybe, 'duty' or 'faith' is also applicable instead of 'obligation'.

When one is doing self-sacrificing acts to follow his/her obligation, what word can describe one's frame of mind best?

Suppose NAVY SEAL team members say "No one left behind", what emotion or resolution will appear in their mind?

Comment: *****Jihad*****

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about emotional responses to loyalty-inducing mottoes, rather than the specifics of any particular *English words or syntax* used in those mottoes.

Comment: "What word can describe one's frame of mind best?" How about "F***!"

Comment: In my opinion, the question is on topic. Clear explanation with an example. The word does not have to apply to the example he gave only (or just to the motto).

Comment: Blessed Geek, **struggle or striving**? http://www.gainpeace.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=121:what-is-the-meaning-of-jihad&catid=54&Itemid=121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first word that comes to mind is **dedication**.  The Marine moto semper fi(delis) means always faithful which works too.  But their system of *brotherhood* works on their dedication to themselves and their country.

Comment: FYI: *Semper fi* is the motto of the *Marines*. The Navy Seals' motto is *"Ready to Lead, Ready to Follow, Never Quit"*.

Comment: @medica - brain fart was typing two things at once. thanks

Answer (score 5):

*[Allegiance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/allegiance)*

> Loyalty or the obligation of loyalty, as to a nation, sovereign, or cause.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=allegiance) says:

> General figurative sense of "recognition of claims to respect or duty" is attested from 1732.

From [U.S. Army](http://www.army.mil/values/index.html) website: (under "army values")

> Bear true faith and **allegiance** to the U.S. Constitution, the Army, **your unit and other Soldiers**. Bearing true faith and allegiance is a matter of believing in and **devoting yourself to something or someone**. A loyal Soldier is one who supports the leadership and **stands up for fellow Soldiers**.

---

Also, *devotion* and *fidelity* come second.

Answer (score 3):

I would use *resolve* for the quality you are seeking.

Wounded and weary, he nevertheless met every challenge with steely *resolve*.

Firm determination to do something:

She received information that strengthened her resolve.

She intended to stick to her initial resolve.

Or, as a verb, "We here highly *resolve* that these dead shall not have died in vain."

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/resolve?q=resolve

Answer (score 3):

[*Selflessness*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/selflessness)

> Having, exhibiting, or motivated by no concern for oneself; unselfish

and [*altruism*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/altruism)

> Unselfish concern for the welfare of others; selflessness

come to mind.

Comment: I know the definitions are known to you, and also you know about our site's preference about definitions and link rot. You should really include them in most cases.

Comment: @medica - Fair point. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Great. Thanks for respecting the site recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

One of the main  traits of all military codes is:  [Obedience](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obedience):

> - the act or practice of obeying; dutiful or submissive compliance: 
>     Military service demands obedience from its members.

Ex: The 1968 My Lai massacre was a military crime of [obedience](https://www.ncjrs.gov/App/publications/abstract.aspx?ID=138534).

Answer (score 1):

What first comes to mind is *cross* and *ordeal*.

> [cross](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross?show=0&t=1401410149): an affliction that tries one's virtue, steadfastness, or patience
>
> [a cross (somebody has) to carry (or bear)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+cross+to+bear): an unpleasant situation or responsibility that you must accept because you cannot change it
>
> [ordeal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ordeal): an experience that is very difficult or unpleasant

Alternately, consider *resignation* and *strength and honor*.

> [resignation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resignation): an accepting, unresisting attitude, state, feeling, etc.; submission; acquiescence: *to meet one's fate with resignation*
>
> [strength and honor](http://www.ask.com/question/strength-and-honor-in-latin): frequently used in the day of the warrior, these words were referring to the character of the warrior when fighting

Answer (score 1):

**Conviction**, because action first requires internal agreement, and it is only when you are assured beyond doubt, that you act.

Answer (score 1):

The person would have a [**deontological**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deontic) frame of mind:

> Of, relating to, or concerning duties or obligations: deontic logic.

Answer (score 1):

**Fatalistic** because you know that the result will be your death, but you accept the consequences. Note that this usage would seem to imply a certain passive resignation to one's fate, rather than an active embracing of it.

Or, if you want a slightly different slant on the situation,

**Fey** in its original meaning

"a chiefly Scottish :  fated to die :  doomed

b :  marked by a foreboding of death or calamity " (Merriam Webster)